# How to create a folder in Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

So the new Firebase has support for storage using Google Cloud Platform.

You can upload a file to the `images` folder using:

```
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images').put(file, metadata);
```

What if you want to create a subfolder `images/user1234` dynamically using code?

The offical [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/storage/index.html) does not show how to do that, nor the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#create_a_reference) or [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference).

Is the Firebase Console the only place where folders can be created [manually](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400868?hl=en#create-folder)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Firebase Console does allow you to create a folder, since it's the easiest way to add files to a specific folder there.

But there is no public API to create a folder. Instead folders are auto-created as you add files to them.

Firebase Storage is based on Google Cloud Storage. See the [documentation provided by GCS about the illusion of folders](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders).

Answer (score 54):

The Firebase Storage API dynamically creates "folders" as intermediate products: if you create a file at `images/user1234/file.txt`, all intermediate "folders" like "images" and "user1234" will be created along the way. So your code becomes:

```
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/user1234/file.txt').put(file, metadata);
```

Note that you need to include the file name (`foo.txt` for example) in the `child()` call, since the reference should include the full path as well as the file name, otherwise your file will be called `images`.

Comment: Can we upload a folder in the storage console?

Comment: This gives me "_filePath.includes is not a function"... any idea why that could be? The path I'm passing to .child() looks correct (printed it to the console to be sure).

Answer (score 7):

Firebase is lacking very important functionality, there's always the need to be doing some tricks to emulate behaviours that should be standard.

- If you create a folder **manually from the Firebase console** it will
  **persist** even when there are no more files in it.
- If you create a folder **dynamically** and all files get deleted at some
  point, the folder will **disappear** and be deleted as well.

I implemented a file manager using Firebase Storage so when a user wants to upload a file he can do it through this interface not from something external to the app as is the Firebase Console. You want to give the user the option to reorganize the files as he wants, but something as common as creating a new folder cannot be done without tricks, why? just because this is Firebase.

So in order to emulate this behaviour what I came up with was the following:

1. Create a reference with the new folder name.
2. Create a reference for a "ghost" file as child of the folder's reference and give it always the same fixed name, eg. '.ghostfile'
3. Upload the file to this newly created folder. Any method is valid, I just use [uploadString](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string).
4. Every time I list the files of a reference, exclude any file named as before. So this "ghost" file is not shown in the file manager.

So an example to create a foler:

```
async function createFolder (currentRef: StorageReference, folderName: string) {
        const newDir = ref(currentRef, name)
        const ghostFile = ref(newDir, '.ghostfile')
        await uploadString(ghostFile, '')
}
```

And an example to list the files:

```
async function loadLists (ref: StorageReference) {
    const { prefixes, items } = await listAll(ref)
    return {
        directories: prefixes,
        files: items.filter(file => file.name !=== '.ghostfile')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You most certainly can create directories... with a little bit of playing with the references I did the following.

```
test = (e,v) => {
    let fileName = "filename"
    let newDirectory = "someDir"
    let storage = firebase.storage().ref(`images/${newDirectory}/${fileName}`)

    let file = e.target.files[0]
    if(file !== undefined && file.type === "image/png" ) {
        storage.put(file)
            .then( d => console.log('you did it'))
            .catch( d => console.log("do something"))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You know the answer is really the same between Frank, Mike and me just said different ways...

Comment: your answer doesn't use .child() and puts the folder path right in the ref() instead of child. Which, in AngularFire, actually worked the way I was expecting. Where I had an issue with erroneous parent folders in Mike's example. Maybe a quirk with AngularFire syntax. Options are always good.

Answer (score 4):

```
String myFolder = "MyImages";
StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child(myFolder).child("images/pic.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase console allows you to create a folder. I don't think there is another way to create a folder.