# How to create a folder in Firebase Storage with PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-storage

My problem tried to create a small script that allows me to create a **folder** and within this a **file** (jpg) in the **Firebase** **Storage**. I found on the [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664385/how-to-create-a-folder-in-firebase-storage) that just placing the name of the **folder** before the name of the **file** should be generated, but the file is not generated and loaded. The file is only loaded when I manually create the folder in **Storage**.

**My upload code:**

```
public function upload(){
        $this->bucket->upload(
            file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']),
            [
                'name' => "ena/" . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']
            ]
        );
}
```

I am using the [Kreait](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#usage-example) library. **Thank** you and I look forward to your support.

Comment: I tested this locally (with an already present file, not with $_FILES) and it worked for me. Could you debug this by debugging the contents of `file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])` and of `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']` to make sure that a) there are file contents and b) that the target path/file name are as you expect? I would also recommend using `move_uploaded_file()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) first, and then using `$this->bucket->upload()` with the moved uploaded file.

Comment: friend thanks for your support. But do you automatically generate the folder?

Comment: Yes, it does for me, that's why I was suggesting the debugging steps and using `move_uploaded_files()`, because that's the difference in my local test script.

Comment: ok I'm going to try, but if you can load that fraction of code to guide me. I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks **jeromegamez**, the code that implements and works correctly for me. Whose logic is simple, it receives the file and moves it to the server and once moved it loads it to firebase storage.

```
$target_path = "uploads/"; 

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    $name =  $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 

        $myfile = fopen($target_path, "r")  ;

        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 

        $this->bucket->upload($myfile, [
            'name' => $_POST["proyecto"] . "/" . $name
        ]);

    } else{ 
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
    }
```