# i wanna save my uploaded images in a folder firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

i wanna save my uploaded images in a folder called "course-cover" in firebase storage
this is my code that saves uploaded images in the route of storage directly but instead of thet i wanna save them in the "course-cover" folder

```
 async function storeCoverCourse(coverCourse) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const filename = `${coverCourse.name}-${uuidv4()}`;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, filename);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, coverCourse);
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
        // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case "paused":
            console.log("Upload is paused");
            break;
          case "running":
            console.log("Upload is running");
            break;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        reject(error);
      },
      () => {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          resolve(downloadURL);
        });
      }
    );
  });
}

const imgUrls = await Promise.all(
  [...cover].map((coverCourse) => storeCoverCourse(coverCourse))
).catch((error) => {
  toast.error("image not uploaded");
  return;
});

const formDataCopy = {
  ...formData,
  imgUrls,
  timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
};
delete formDataCopy.cover;
await addDoc(collection(db, "courses"), formDataCopy);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the solution that [@Dharmaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13130697) [covered in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75125159/3068190), you should also get rid of the [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/3068190) use of the Promise constructor with Promise returning functions. It can be eliminated because the `uploadTask` object is a thenable/promise-like object.

```
async function storeCoverCourse(coverCourse) {
  const storage = getStorage();
  const filename = `course-cover/${coverCourse.name}-${uuidv4()}`;
  const storageRef = ref(storage, filename);
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, coverCourse);
  
  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {
      // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
      // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
      const progress =
        (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case "paused":
          console.log("Upload is paused");
          break;
        case "running":
          console.log("Upload is running");
          break;
      }
    }
  );

  return uploadTask
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `storageRef` is a [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.storagereference) and you essentially specify path of your file with it. If your path contains `/`, that'll be like a directory. Try:

```
const filename = `course-cover/${coverCourse.name}-${uuidv4()}`;
const storageRef = ref(storage, filename);
```

It's not actually a folder under the hood but just a namespace. For more details, see [How to create a folder in Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664385/how-to-create-a-folder-in-firebase-storage/37666877#37666877)